# Find $f_n,h_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,1]\times\Omega\times[0,1]}(h_n(r,y)f_n(x)-X(r,y,x))^2d(\lambda\otimes P\otimes\lambda)(r,y,x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

We consider a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P),$ and for $(r,\omega,x) \in [0,1] \times \Omega \times [0,1],$ a bounded $\mathcal{B}([0,1]) \otimes \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{B}([0,1])$-measurable function $X(r,\omega,x).$

Prove that there exist sequences $(h_n)_{n}$ and $(f_n)_n$ such that $h_n$ is a bounded $\mathcal{B}([0,1]) \otimes \mathcal{F}$-measurable function, $f_n$ is a bounded $\mathcal{B}([0,1])$-measurable function and $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{[0,1] \times \Omega \times [0,1]}(h_n(r,\omega)f_n(x)-X(r,\omega,x))^2d(\lambda \otimes P \otimes \lambda)(r,\omega,x)=0.$$

I tried to explicit $f_n,h_n$ as functions of $X,$ but this didn't work.

Any ideas how to find $f_n$ and $h_n$?